# Android Studio 2 Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, default, build.gradle

This question has been asked many times so far, but none of the provided solutions worked for me.

I'm completely new to Android Studio and trying to open this project in Android Studio: https://github.com/monkeyswarm/MobMuPlat.

There is two `build.gradle` files. One in the root folder and another in in the 'app' folder. is that correct?

When I try to sync the gradle project it says gradle project sync failed and gives me the error: Configuration with name 'default' not found.

This part in the `build.gradle` file is highlighted:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

any idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: and how you are importing?

Comment: Post error message or screenshot.

Comment: Show your settings.gradle file

Comment: The highlight is due to the fact that you're using Android Studio 2 with the Gradle plugin 1.5. You should update the plugin to version 2.0.0: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

Comment: problem is solved. there was a superfluous line in the settings.gradle file causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **app/build.gradle** is containing one line

```
 wearApp project(':mobmuplatandroidwear')
```

Remove that and try to sync the project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your [`MobMuPlat-Android/settings.gradle`](https://github.com/monkeyswarm/MobMuPlat/blob/master/MobMuPlat-Android/settings.gradle) you are defining:

```
include ':app', ':mobmuplatandroidwear'
```

Gradle is searching for a `build.gradle` in the `mobmuplatandroidwear` module which is not present.